# xpath to read edmx file EntityTypes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, edmx

I need to update StoreGeneratedPattern to "None" in edmx file programmaticaly for Property nodes, based on some criteara like Name attribute contains "Code" value, what will be XPath to select such Property elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="Model.Store" Provider="System.Data.CData.DynamicsCRM" ProviderManifestToken="DynamicsCRM" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityType Name="Account">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="varchar" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="AccountCategoryCode" Type="varchar" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
          <Property Name="AccountClassificationCode" Type="varchar" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
          <Property Name="AccountNumber" Type="varchar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Root;


            XElement entityType = root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "EntityType").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = entityType.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement toChange = entityType.Elements(ns + "Property").Where(x => ((string)x.Attribute("Name")).Contains("Code")).FirstOrDefault();
            toChange.SetAttributeValue("StoreGeneratedPattern", "None");
        }
    }
}
```